# Computer Precision in C language

Tags: c

I find intriguing some features on C programming and computer precision. 
For example, in my computer if I print the DBL_MANT_DIG variable (of limits.h library) that indicates the bit precision of a double, it returns  64. That means 64bits of mantissa. And that means I can store up to 19 digits in the mantissa.
However if I ask the computer to print more digits, say `printf("%.40lf",...),`it still does print them. What are those digits and where are they stored?

Another thing is that if a print the variable DBL_MAX I get: `179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368`
This has more than 19 digits. Where are they stored again?

To print this numbers I do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(void)
{

    printf("Double Min/Max: %lf %lf\n", DBL_MIN, DBL_MAX);
    printf("Digits mantissa (bit precission) double: %d\n", DBL_MANT_DIG);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should show some code. How did you print DBL_MAX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(An [IEEE double-precision floating point value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) has a 52-bit mantissa, not 64-bit.)

You can think of floating-point numbers as being stored in the binary equivalent of scientific notation. Even though the number you posted has "more than 19 digits," it can still be represented using only 52 mantissa bits.

Imagine you have a mantissa that holds 4 decimal digits, and a 3 decimal digit exponent. This is a floating point number, but in decimal, not binary. The maximum representable value here is 9999e999 (= 9999 * 10<sup>999</sup>), the decimal expansion of which clearly has far more than 4 digits. But it is *representable* using 4 decimal digits and a 3-digit exponent.

Comment: $10^{999}$ has more digits, but they are trailing zeros. Not a sequence of numbers.

Comment: @JanusGowda The digits wouldn't be zeroes if you then represented it in a different base.

Comment: @TypelA So if the operation gives an infinite sequence, does the computer calculate this while it prints? This is interesting.

Comment: `DBL_MANT_DIG` in _not_ the length of the mantissa.  It is the length of the significand, which is 53 in [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point: binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: @JanusGowda A conversion from a finite binary representation to decimal will always be finite, so the situation you describe won't arise. But it could arise going the opposite direction, converting from decimal to binary. This is in fact what happens when you write a floating-point literal that isn't exactly representable: the compiler rounds it to the nearest representable value.

Comment: @TypeIA This doubt arises because in mathematics teachers always say that if we use double we have 16 digits of precision approximately. Then how can I be sure of how many digits of precision my maths programs give?

Comment: @JanusGowda Understandable! In general the result of a single double-precision floating-point calculation, printed in decimal, will be accurate up to *roughly* the 16th decimal digit. That doesn't mean there are no more digits after that, just that they're no longer accurate because you have exceeded the value's precision limit. Note that this is no longer true if you have a sequence of calculations because rounding errors can accumulate from sequential calculations.

Comment: @TypeIA All clear now. Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a thought experiment. Consider the fraction 3/7. Print it as a decimal.

```
0.428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571...
```

Where are the digits stored?

Comment: Are you meaning that operations are performed on printing time?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the number 1/8. It can be represented with only an exponent and no mantissa. Yet it's decimal representation 0.125 has 3 nonzero digits. The decimal representation is computed during printing. Internally a binary representation with a base 2 exponent is used.